# Draw the enantiomer products of the reaction between 1,3‐butadiene and (3Z)‐pent‐3‐en‐2‐one

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: 1,3‐butadiene and (3Z)‐pent‐3‐en‐2‐one]

From this reactants I need to draw two products with cyclohexene rings that are enantiomers to each other with chemical formula $\ce{C9H14O}.$ And also draw the reaction mechanisms. Why does it form enantiomers? I'm not sure how I should approach this.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE! It would be helpful to add more specifics. What are the conditions of temperature, solvent and pH? What are your attempts at solving this problem? Help us help you!

Comment: Do you know how a [4+2] cycloaddition works?